# Multiple spring Kafka stream processors in one spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have a requirement to write 2 Spring Kafka Stream processors in one spring-boot application. Both stream processors need to consume messages from a **single topic** and produce the output to another **single topic**.
The first processor does not process all messages coming to the input topic, it processes some selected messages (group by message key) and uses **windowedBy** option instead.

The second processor, however, needs to process all messages which do not fall into the first processor **groupBy** logic.

I started with the first processor which works fine. The problem came when I try to introduce the second processor.

**KafkaProcessor.java:**

```
    @Bean
    public Function<KStream<String, Input>, KStream<String, Output>> processorOne() {
    
        final AtomicReference<KeyValue<String, Output>> result = new AtomicReference<>(null);
        return kStream -> kStream
            .filter((key, value) -> value != null)
            .filter(this::isValidKey)
            .peek((key, value) -> print(value))
            .groupBy((key, value) -> key)
            .windowedBy(TimeWindows.ofSizeWithNoGrace(Duration.ofMinutes(5)))
            .count(Materialized.as("my-state-store"))
            .filter((windowedKey, count) -> count > 0)
            .toStream()
            .filter((messageKey, messageValue) -> {
              log.info("Key: {} count: {}", messageKey.key(), messageValue);
              Optional<Output> outputResult = service.process(messageKey.key());
              if (outputResult.isPresent()) {
                Output output = outputResult.get();
                print(output);
                result.set(KeyValue.pair(messageKey.key(), output));
                return true;
              }
              return false;
            })
            .map((messageKey, messageValue) -> result.get());
      }
```

Then I added, a second processor to the same class.

```
@Bean
  public Function<KStream<String, Input>, KStream<String, Output>> processorTwo() {
    final AtomicReference<KeyValue<String, Output>> result = new AtomicReference<>(null);
    return kStream -> kStream
        .filter((key, value) -> value != null)
        .filter((key, value) -> isValidEvent(value))
        .peek((key, value) -> print(value))
        .filter((messageKey, messageValue) -> {
          Optional<Output> outputResult = service.process(messageValue);
          if (outputResult.isPresent()) {
            Output output = outputResult.get();
            print(output);
            result.set(KeyValue.pair(String.format("%s-%s", output.getNameOne(), output.getNametwo()), output));
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        })
        .map((messageKey, messageValue) -> result.get());
  }
```

**application.yaml**

```
    spring:
  application:
    name: my-common-processor
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: processorOne; processorTwo
      bindings:
        processorOne-in-0:
          destination: input-topic
          group: ${spring.application.name}-processorOne
        processorOne-out-0:
          destination: output-topic
          group: ${spring.application.name}-processorOne
        processorTwo-in-0:
          destination: input-topic
          group: ${spring.application.name}-processorTwo
        processorTwo-out-0:
          destination: output-topic
          group: ${spring.application.name}-processorTwo
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: 127.0.0.1:9092
          auto-create-topics: false
          auto-add-partitions: false
        streams:
          binder:
            configuration:
              spring.json.use.type.headers: false
              spring.json.trusted.packages: '*'
              max.poll.records: 10
              max.block.ms: 5000
              default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
              default.value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
            deserialization-exception-handler: sendtodlq
            auto-create-topics: false
            auto-add-partitions: false
            functions:
              processorOne:
                application-id: ${spring.application.name}-processorOne
              processorTwo:
                application-id: ${spring.application.name}-processorTwo
          bindings:
            processorOne-in-0:
              consumer:
                dlqName: error-topic
            processorTwo-in-0:
              cosumer:
                dlqName: error-topic
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: 127.0.0.1:9092 // for kafka admin
```

Questions:

1. Is this the correct way to do this?
2. With this setup, the second processor never processes any messages even the messages which should have been processed by it.
3. If the setup is correct, how do I add/configure a deserialization-exception-handler for each processor?

Answer (score 1):

This is where low level processor API implementation comes into picture. Define your project in this way.

1. Write a filtering processor that extends an abstract processor to filter the event from input topic(Hope your event will have a field which describes EventType1 or EventType2). Use the context forwarder inside the override process method. I would call this as EventFilteringProcessor.

if (EventType1)
context.forward(key, value, To.child(EventType1));

if (EventType2)
context.forward(key, value, To.child(EventType2));

2. Write two separate processor instances i.e. two separate classes that would extends AbstractProcessor. I would call these classes as EventType1Processor and EventType2Processor.
3. Describe your stream processor topology in the following way, in the main Spring boot application that implements the ProcessController.

   ```
        Topology topology = new Topology();
        topology.addSource("Source", "YourInputTopic)
                .addProcessor("EventFilterClass", () -> EventFilteringProcessor.class, "Source")
                .addProcessor(EventType1, () -> EventType1Processor.class, "EventFilterClass")
                .addProcessor(EventType2, () -> EventType2Processor.class, "EventFilterClass");

        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, streamConfig);
        streams.start();
   ```
4. You can have your respective business logic in the respective override process methods of EventType1Processor and EventType2Processor.

Hope this helps.